# Deriving from arbitrary Python class with C API and `tp_basicsize` of `object`?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am trying to define a function, that would create a Python class using C API, that derives from arbitrary Python type `base`, and has an extra field `void* my_ptr` in its raw C-like object layout. I want it to reuse Python's `__dict__` functionality.

I am not doing it in C, so don't have access to C macros. My initial attempt looks like this (pseudocode):

```
PyType Derive(PyType base) {
  var newType = new PyType(...);

  newType.tp_flags = HeapType | BaseType; // <- this is important,
    // one should be able to add new attributes and otherwise use __dict__, subclass, etc

  ... filling in other things ...

  int my_ptr_offset = base.tp_basesize; // put my_ptr immediately after base type data
  newType.tp_basesize = my_ptr_offset + sizeof(void*); // instances of new type
    // will have instance size = base size + size of my_ptr

  ...

  return newType;
}
```

The problem is this code breaks down when `base` is `builtins.object`. In that case `tp_basesize` does not count the field, that would normally store `__dict__`, and `my_ptr_offset` ends up pointing to that field, eventually causing it to be overwritten by the consumer of `my_ptr`.

Any simple Python class that derives from `object` does not have that problem. E.g.:

```
class MySimpleClass: pass
```

On 64-bit machine:

```
PyType mySimpleClass = ...;
PyType object = ...;
mySimpleClass.tp_basesize // <- 32, includes __dict__
object.tp_basesize // <- 16, does not include space for __dict__
```

I also noticed a similar problem with `builtins.exception`.

Right now I just manually check for `exception` and `object` and add 2x `sizeof(void*)` to `tp_basesize`, which seems to work. But I'd like to understand how to handle that layout properly.

Comment: If you're not doing this in C, what language *are* you doing it in?

Comment: C#. See https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the information you want is in [`tp_dictoffset`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dictoffset) of the base. If this is set to 0 then the base doesn't have a `__dict__`, anything else and it does.

I'm a little unclear on how you're creating your types, but at-least through a call to `PyType_Type` (the method used internally when writing `class X:` in Python) a dict is added unless `__slots__` is defined - it sounds like this is both what you want to happen and what is happening. This is detailed under "Inheritance" in the section of documentation I linked.

Therefore, if `tp_dictoffset == 0` (and assuming you aren't defining `__slots__`) then add `sizeof(PyObject*)` to account for the dictionary that's implicitly added.

Comment: The thing is, as you can see from the example above, there are actually 2 pointer-sized objects added. Do you know which one is the second one?

Comment: @LOST: That'd be `__weakref__`. It's unclear where `__dict__` or `__weakref__` would even be coming from with code anything like your pseudocode, though, or why they would be allocated over your field instead of afterward if you adjusted `tp_basicsize` like you show.

Comment: `__dict__` and `__weakref__` don't come from the `Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` flag. If they're not provided by the base class already, then `type_new` adds them, unless `__slots__` says not to. You don't seem to be calling `type_new`.

Comment: I suspect (and hope) that `new PyType(...)` is really just a C# wrapping round `type_new`. But this seems like the sort of thing that @LOST should be very sure of

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica @DavidW what is the `type_new` you are referring to? We use `PyType_GenericAlloc` and then fill the struct.

Comment: It's effectively the C equivalent of `type.__new__` - I'd probably access it by calling `type` through `PyObject_CallObject(PyType_Type, ...)` or similar.